# Stars moving in line and some moves around

Tags: star

I am from South Africa this morning around 05:00 I saw 7 to 9 stars moving in line and some moves around. What cause that to happen. Because I have never saw  something like that before.

Comment: Now you'll never be able to say "I have never saw something like that before" again! :-)

Comment: The person responsible is also from South Africa. Coincidence!

Comment: New launch March 18. :(